# How to store video's in coredata swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I need to download  video for offline usesing Core Data. i haven't used core data before please some one explain step by step process

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This is not a tutoring / consulting service.  You should try to solve the problem yourself (reading any tutorials and documentation available online), push through issues through researching the problems encountered, and then, after doing those two things, if you run into issues that you cannot solve, post an [mcve] that outlines the *specific* problem you are noticing, along with any research you've done and measures you've taken to try and handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For files like video what you do is downloading the video into the Documents or Cache folder of your app and store the file path (URL) to the video in the core data table

Comment: thankyou leonid Usov i dunno how to store that url into coreData